# Setting background colour on accordion-header based on variable

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, ui.bootstrap

I have the following HTML that uses the UI.Bootstrap accordion control

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="kvp in jobTemplate.jobMasterConfigGroups[$index].jobMasterConfigs" is-open="kvp.active">
                                        <accordion-heading>
                                            <i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-minus': kvp.active, 'fa-plus': !kvp.active}"></i>
                                            <span>Key: <strong>{{kvp.key | cut:false:15}}</strong> Value: <strong>{{kvp.value | cut:false:50}}</strong></span>
                                        </accordion-heading>
....
```

What I want is for the accordion-heading to be a different colour (the entire heading bar background) if kvp.IsOverridden == true

I'm not sure of the best way to do this, can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a class on the `accordion-group` when the property is true, and add a CSS rule to style the header of a group with that class:

JS:

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="kvp in jobTemplate.jobMasterConfigGroups[$index].jobMasterConfigs" is-open="kvp.active" ng-class="{'overridden': kvp.IsOverridden}">
    <accordion-heading>
        <i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-minus': kvp.active, 'fa-plus': !kvp.active}"></i>
        <span>Key: <strong>{{kvp.key | cut:false:15}}</strong> Value: <strong>{{kvp.value | cut:false:50}}</strong></span>
    </accordion-heading>
</accordion-group>
```

CSS:

```
.overridden .panel-heading {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, thanks for the response. I have tried the above but I didn't see any visual change in the website. I changed the attribute on the accordion group to class="overridden" and they all turned red, so it is finding my style, but when I use ng-class="overridden" (even without the logic) it doesn't go red so it's not picking it up from ng-class

Comment: Try to replace the 'kvp.IsOverridden' with 'true' and see if it works